# Android - Pending Intent with flags

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, android-widget

So I have an app with widgets that uses PendingIntent when updating the widgets or opening the app. After setting the targetSdkVersion to 31 it started crashing saying

"Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles "

So I have done like this wherever I use PendingIntent

```
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
            } else {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            }
```

However, it seems like this doesn´t work and it keeps crashing for some users and shows up in Firebase Crashlytics. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "it keeps crashing for some users" -- is it crashing with the same error, or with some new error?

Comment: It´s always the error that I posted starting with "Targeting S+...."

Comment: Perhaps the `PendingIntent` is not coming from your code, but rather from a library. Does the error or stack trace give you any indication of where the `PendingIntent` is coming from?

Comment: That´s a good point. Could be. It says it happens within 1 second of opening the app, that´s why I´m thinking it is from my widgets but I guess it could be from push notifications too so Firebase in that case

Comment: Your new PendingIntent for API 31+ is missing the original flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

If your 'pre API 31'-PendingIntent had this flag, then your 'API 31+'-PendingIntent should have this flag in addition to the IMMUTABLE flag:

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

- But, I'm not sure if this is the reason for the crash in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to perform a runtime check on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` if your apps  `minSdkVersion` is [below SDK 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE).

Otherwise just combine the flags:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand when to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Comment: Looks like the Navgraph stuff has NavDeepLinkBuilder that potentially can build an Intent without those flags.  Might be why my app is fine but fails on androidTest builds on a real phone using 12, emulator tests pass with flying colors.